# How many farms have exactly two of these types of animals?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> There are $323$ farms which have at least one of horses, cows and sheep. If $224$ have horses, $85$ have cows, $57$ have sheep and $18$ have all three types of animals, how many farms have exactly two of these types of animals$?$

As I knew $N=(R-1)k+1$ where $N=\text{pigeons},k=\text{pigeonhole},R=\text{desire output}$. Hence using $R=2$ and $k=3$ $$N=(2-1)3+1=4$$ But I think I am wrong.

---

Additionally for self-confidence I want to know "Is there any trick to choose $N$ and $k?$"

Answer (score 3):

Using [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inclusion-ExclusionPrinciple.html)

$$0=\text{Whole count}-(\underbrace{(A+B+C)}-(\underbrace{AB+BC+CA})+ABC)$$

$$=323-(224+85+57-(\underbrace{AB+BC+CA})+18)$$

Comment: how am I supposed to complete it$?$ and thanks for response

Comment: You're right, of course, but I find the parentheses somewhat confusing. I'd put them either separately around the individual terms, with alternating signs:

$$
=323-(224+85+57)+(AB+BC+CA)-18
$$

or nested around each stage, with minus signs:

$$
=323-(224+85+57-(AB+BC+CA-18))
$$

To my mind, the way you're writing it somewhat obscures the system behind it.

Comment: I need the sum of $AB+BC+CA$ but from $323-(224+85+57-(AB+BC+CA)+18)$ how could I$?$  @joriki

Comment: @MaishaZaman, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inclusion-ExclusionPrinciple.html

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: I think it's not clear to the OP that the expression you wrote (twice in two different forms) is equal to $0$; this should perhaps be included in the answer.

Comment: @joriki, Thanks for the feedback

Comment: are you sure the right hand side is equal to zero$?$ Or it just a typo @labbhattacharjee

Comment: @emonHR,   Whole count = $$\underbrace{(A+B+C)}-(\underbrace{AB+BC+CA})+ABC $$  right?